# Docker container exit (1) error when starting fabric-composer on WSL (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: hyperledger-composer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Trying to run the fabric-composer on windows 10 WSL (Ubuntu 16.04).

After running the ./startFabric.sh get the following error:

[image]

Checking the docker containers only couchdb was running rest exited (1):

[image]

Checking the fabric-ca container logs this was the error:

[image]

Running out of ideas, because the same code is running fabric-composer on a dedicated ubuntu VM.

Any help ?

Comment: technically you are trying to run fabric and you are trying to drive it from WSL shell though routing the docker CLI to talk to a docker daemon running outside of WSL. The fabric-dev-servers package provided by composer doesn't support that configuration.

Comment: hmm, so is there any other way i can run composer on WSL. As the docker engine cannot be inside the WSL, any resource or hack that comes to mind ? looking at any solution that allows me to run composer in wsl

Comment: Composer itself can run in WSL but it's the fabric you are trying to setup and drive from WSL. Composer doesn't bundle a fabric, it can work with almost any fabric setup. the fabric-dev-servers package is just one we provide for convenience to get you started quickly. you could take a look at https://davidkel.github.io/docs/Windows/Intro.html to see if it can help you